# How to set border on tables

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

Suppose I have a `table` element with good amounts of data.

```css
table {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
      <td>My Name</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What would be the best way to set a border of `border-style: dashed; border-color: black; border-size: 3px;` on each even `td`.

Please explain this.

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
td:nth-child(even) {
   border-style: dashed; 
   border-color: black; 
   border-size: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative to my answer, if not better. +1 upvote.

Comment: @Om Mandarwan here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/turijs/j4pyyt3s/). The nth-child selector is new in CSS3, so it won't work in certain older browsers, notably IE8 and earlier.